# matrix question based on $\omega$ : cube root unity

Tags: matrices

let $\omega$ be a complex cube root of unity with $\omega \neq 1$ and $P = [p_{ij}]$ be $n\times n$ matrix with 
$$p_{ij} = \omega^{i+j}$$
Then $P^2$ is not equal to zero where $n$ is equal to

$ (a) \ 57  \\  (b)\ 55,58,56  \\   (c)\ 56,48,57   \\   (d) \ 90,56,57$

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The way the possible answers are grouped is very twisted !!!

Answer (score 3):

**Trick**: The shortest approach, in an MCQ scenario would be to work out $P^2$ for a few basic matrices.

That is, for $n=2$, $P^2$  would not be a zero matrix.

For $n=3$, the matrix $P$ according to the prescribed condition is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        \omega^2 & 1 & \omega \\
        1 & \omega & \omega^2 \\
        \omega & \omega^2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Using basic matrix multiplication and applying the identity $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$, it is easily seen that $P^2$ is the zero matrix.

Keeping this in mind, we can infer a general rule:

for $n \ne 3m, m\in \mathbb N\implies P^2 \ne 0$

From this you can workout the options.

Comment: [+1] You have found the trick (of this very tricky and un-paedagogical exercice)! Maybe, it should be said that if you call $P_3$ the $3 \times 3$  matrix that you have used, if one has a $3n \times 3n$  matrix, call it $Q$,  of the general type, it can be partitionned into $n \times n$ blocks constituted by $P_3$ matrices, explaining that in this case $Q^2=0$.

Comment: ... thus the good answer is (b). I am curious to know the book you are working with...

Comment: But what should be the answer

Comment: How ? Answer is b . please give me more illustration

Comment: @Anshi Look for the multiples of $3$ in each option. Relate it with the general rule obtained.

Comment: How 55 is possible

Comment: @Anshi $55$ is possible for the same reason $58$ and $56$ is possible. Are these numbers multiples of $3$? What can we say if they are not? Think about it.